# Lone Navigation Bar height vs Navigation Bar height in navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I was creating an app where there is a view controller presented as a pop over, but when I try to present the view controller, the navigation bar that isn't part of the navigation controller overlaps with the status bar. The height on the attributes inspector reads 44 for the navigation bar.

[image]

On the other hand, I have another navigation bar inside a navigation controller, and with the attributes inspector still reading 44, it produces a completely different result.

[image]

Could this be a problem with constraints? Or is a navigation controller's navigation bar size larger for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have added a navigation bar to a **Add League** `UIViewController`. The solution would be using a navigation controller with **Add League** as its child controller.